# Return an anonymous list from a List of dictionaries<string, string> where the key equals a value

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` called `data`. I want to use LINQ to return 3 values where the keys equal a term.

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> data = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>
    {
        new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "INDGEN", "100"},
            { "NO", "101"},
            { "DATE", "JUN"},
            { "PRD", "1"}
        },
        new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "INDGEN", "200"},
            { "NO", "101"},
            { "DATE", "JULY"},
            { "PRD", "2"}
        },
        new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "INDGEN", "300"},
            { "NO", "101"},
            { "DATE", "AUG"},
            { "PRD", "3"}
        },
        new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "NO", "400"},
            { "INDGEN", "101"},
            { "DATE", "SEP"},
            { "PRD", "4"}
        },
        new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "INDGEN", "500"},
            { "NO", "101"},
            { "DATE", "OCT"},
            { "PRD", "5"}
        },
        new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "NO", "600"},
            { "INDGEN", "101"},
            { "DATE", "NOV"},
            { "PRD", "6"}
        }
    };
```

Above is an example List. I want to be able to return the `"INDGEN"`, `"DATE"` and `"PRD"` values

> Current implementation:

```
data.SelectMany(x => x.Where(y => y.Key == "INDGEN" || 
             y.Key == "DATE" || y.Key == "PRD" )).Select(z => z.Value);
```

> Current Outcome:

```
100
JUN
1 
200
AUG
2
300
SEP
3
101
OCT
4
500
NOV
5
101
DEC
6
```

The above returns the correct items but doesn't group them into an anonymous collection. How can I extend the above to get the desired outcome shown below?

> Desired Outcome:

```
{"JUN", "100", "1"},
{"JULY", "200", "2"},
{"AUG", "300", "3"},
{"SEP", "400", "4"},
{"OCT", "500", "5"},
{"NOV", "600", "6"}
```

Comment: The way to attack this problem is to solve it for a *single* dictionary and produce a *single* record first. Suppose you have a dictionary, not a list of dictionaries, and you want to produce one such record. Can you solve the problem for that scenario? Can you show us the code that solves that problem? Do so by writing a method, `ExtractRecord`, say, that solves the simpler problem. Then the more complex problem is easy to solve; it is `data.Select(ExtractRecord).ToList()`

Comment: That assumes we are guaranteed that each dictionary is capable of producing a record; is that true in your scenario?

Comment: Collections of Dictionaries allways make me feel "huuuugh???!!!" Usually they serve a certain purpose and have a certain amount of properties which makes them good candidates for a class. Far better to understand and to maintain - in particular when your objects become more complex.

Comment: @EricLippert The dictionary will always produce a record with values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try making a record from *each* dictionary:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> data = ...

var result = data
  .Select(dict => 
     new {
       date = dict.TryGetValue("DATE", out var dateVal) ? dateVal : null,
       indGen = dict.TryGetValue("INDGEN", out var indGenVal) ? indGenVal : null,
       prd = dict.TryGetValue("PRD", out var prdVal) ? prdVal : null
   })
   // If we want to remove incomplete records
  .Where(item => item.date != null && item.indGen != null && item.prd != null);
```

Comment: This is a good solution; were I writing it, I'd make a helper method `V GetValueOrDefault<K, V>(this Dict<K, V> d, K k) => d.TryGetValue(k, out var v) ? v : default(V);` and now your projection is much cleaner: `date = dict.GetValueOrDefault("DATE"), … `

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following. Keeping in mind you can change the default values

```
var anonCollection = data.Where(d => d.GetValueOrDefault("DATE", null) != null && d.GetValueOrDefault("INDGEN", null) != null && d.GetValueOrDefault("PRD", null) != null)
            .Select(d => new []{ d.GetValueOrDefault("INDGEN", null), d.GetValueOrDefault("DATE", null), d.GetValueOrDefault("PRD", null) }).ToList();
```

Comment: If the predicate in the `Where` is true, then the projection in the `Select` will never have the default value, so calling `GetValueOrDefault` is unnecessary.  The `Select` could be just `...{d["INDGEN"], d["DATE"], d["PRD"]}`

Comment: If the key doesn't exist then the predicate in the `Where` is false, which prevents the indexer from crashing because it never runs.